# How to navigate in a WPF Blazor Hybrid app

Tags: c#, wpf, blazor

I created a WPF Blazor Hybrid app using the tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hybrid/tutorials/wpf?view=aspnetcore-8.0

The app's working fine and is starting with a Razor-Page, that is stored into /Pages/Overview.razor

How to navigate to another page like /Pages/Details.razor ?
I tried navigation manager, but the link or button I create didn't do anything

Overview.razor

```html
@inject NavigationManager navManager

<h3>Overview</h3>

<button @onclick="NavigateToDetails">klick me</button>
```

Overview.razor.cs

```cs
namespace Accounting.Pages
{
    public partial class Overview
    {
        private void NavigateToDetails()
        {
            navManager.NavigateTo("/Details");
        }
    }
}
```

(also tried /Pages/Details)